# Download/Display file stored in SQL table

Tags: java, tapestry

I've taken over a project where the file upload functionality is broken. Currently when a file is uploaded it is converted to a byteArray like so and then stored in a SQL table

```
public static byte[] saveAttachment(String filePath) throws IOException{
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
        output.write(buffer, 0 , bytesRead);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    return output.toByteArray();

}
```

I can't say I agree with the approach that has been taken but alas I must work with it. My question becomes how do I go about retrieving this file to display?

I have read 
https://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToStreamAnExistingBinaryFile

And tried (which didn't work)

```
@OnEvent(component="viewAttachment")
private Object viewAttachment(){
final File getFile();
final OutputStreamResponse response = new OutputStreamResponse() {

    public String getContentType() {
        return "image/jpg"; 
    }

    public void prepareResponse(Response response) {
        response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            IOUtils.copy(in,out);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }                   
    }
};
return response;
}
```

However I am not sure this is the proper/optimal solution.

Comment: You file is stored in DB as byte array, right? Why do you convert it to file just to display for client? You can return InputStream from byte array from your DB.

Comment: @xl0e yes it's stored as a byte array. how would I go about displaying these files to the user? The function here is to view uploaded attachments that can be of any file format. The upload portion works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that row.getBytes() returns your image as byte array, and row.getName() is image name:

```
    return new StreamResponse() {

        @Override
        public String getContentType() {
            return "image/jpeg";
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream getStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(row.getBytes());
        }

        @Override
        public void prepareResponse(Response response) {
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + row.getName() + "\"");
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to save the file in a location and save the location in the database. This will help to have size of database.

Also file is available and can retrieve easily without heavy database object.

Or you can add the BLOB column in database and store the file in database.

Convert file into File object

```
File image = new File("D:\\a.gif");
FileInputStream   fis = new FileInputStream(image);
stmt.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) image.length());
```

Add retrieve it using

```
  File image = new File("D:\\java.gif");
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(image);

  byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
  InputStream is = resultSet.getBinaryStream(3);
  while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
    fos.write(buffer);
  }
  fos.close();
```

Comment: I would prefer this approach however at least for the moment my hands are tied

Comment: check now i modify my solution

Comment: I'm using JPA/Eclipselink. What would be the equivalent?